# SQL Request in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, request, fetch

I know how to write the request I need in SQL but can't find a way to implement it using Core Data, or if I find a solution it would be ugly and messy, using 20+ lines of code...

My request is `SELECT MAX(distance) FROM DataTrip WHERE idTrip = (SELECT DISTINCT(idTrip) FROM DataTrip);`

Any idea how I can do that using Core Data with NSSortDescriptor, NSPredicate, NSExpressionDescription, etc.?

Thank you!

**Update 1**

Data model for DataTrip object:

```
@interface DataTrip : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * speed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * heading;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
// More properties here
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idTrip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * distance;

@end
```

So I would have in my database multiple rows with the same idTrip, and I want the max value for distance for each idTrip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is difficult to answer because it hinges on the assumption that SQL and Core Data have anything to do with each other.  They in fact, have very little to do with each other.  Core Data is not a database and should not be thought of as or treated as one.  The way you would accomplish the task you specified in the question is highly dependent on the data model that you have created.  Without that information it's not possible to give any more helpful information.

Comment: I added the model to my post, the DataTrip object. What I have now is doing a first request to get distinct itTrips in an array, then I do a loop on it and try to get the max distance value for this current idTrip... Lots of code and the second part (getting the max value) isn't working yet.

Comment: I would start by creating a fetch request for your DataTrip entity.  Add a sort descriptor that sorts on distance.  Then you should be able to then step through the resulting array and get the information you achieve.  Just to make sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, could you describe what exactly you want to do with this fetch?

Comment: I want to calculate the total distance the user did for all his trips. So for each trip, I need the last record that contains the total distance. That's why I want the max value of distance (distance increments all the time, so the max is the last record) for each trip (represented by an idTrip). I tried a GROUP BY in my predicate but it looks like it does not like it. Any thoughts on GROUP BY? I could group and take the max, which would work.

Comment: Again, that seems like a misuse of Core Data.  If you need to do aggregate operations like that, you might be best using something like FMDB that better fits the paradigms you're used to.  If you are bent on Core Data, I'd split your data model up into a trip, and give it a relationship to trip segments, the sum of all of your trips segments distance would equal the distance of the entire trip.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep it does, that's a good option indeed. For my problem I found a solution but it is not optimized, need some modification on my model to do all that differently. Thanks!